# Making a Swift class conform to a protocol that requires an init

Tags: cocoa, swift, protocols

I have the following `protocol` in `Swift`:

```
protocol FooConvertible{
    typealias FooType

    init(foo: FooType)
}
```

I can make `Swift` classes conform to it in the class definition:

```
class Bar: FooConvertible {
    var baz: String = ""
    required init(foo: String){
        baz = foo
    }
}
```

So far so good. However, the problem arises when I try to make a class conform to it in an extension (With Cocoa classes, it's my only option, as I don't have the source):

```
class Baz {
    var baz = ""
}

extension Baz: FooConvertible{

    required convenience init(foo: String) { // Insists that this should be in the class definition
        baz = foo
    }
}

extension NSURL: FooConvertible{

    required convenience init(foo: String) { // this also fails for the same reason

    }
}
```

This [used to be possible](https://github.com/mattt/Literally/blob/master/Literally.swift), in previous versions of the language

What's the reason it was removed?

That would mean that all the XXXLiteralConvertible Protocols are banned from Cocoa classes!

Comment: That fact is spelled out quite clearly by [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH24-XID_235).

Comment: Where does it say that you may add convenience inits to Swift classes but not to Cocoa classes?

Comment: You are not allowed to do either.  Your example does not compile.

Comment: Crap, I wasn't getting any compiler errors in the playground until now.
you're right and I'll modify the question.

Comment: FYI, there's a discussion on the devforums about the `XXXLiteralConvertible` aspect of this: [StringLiteralConvertible in Swift 1.1 for class](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1057171)

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you are trying to create something like this:

```
protocol FooConvertible : class {
    typealias FooType

    var baz : String { get set } // protocol extensions inits may need to know this

    init(foo: FooType) // this is your designated initializer
}

extension FooConvertible {

    // init(foo: String) {
    //     self.init(foo: foo)
    //     baz = foo
    // }
    // you can't do this because it could call it self recursively 

    init(num: Int) { // this init will call your designated init and can instantiate correctly 
        self.init(foo: "\(num)")
    }
}

class Baz {
    var baz = ""
}

class Bar: FooConvertible {
    var baz: String = ""

    required init(foo: String) { // designated initializer
        baz = foo
    }
}
```

`Baz` will now know about all inits of `FooConvertible`.
If so, I'm glad I could help. :)