# extending Foundation classes to conform to Swift protocol

Tags: swift, protocols, foundation

I am trying to define a protocol for which I would like to add conformance to several Foundation classes as well as some custom types of my own. I first tried doing this with a convenience initializer in the protocol, but that [does not seem possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26876858/making-a-swift-class-conform-to-a-protocol-that-requires-an-init). I read in the [linked thread](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1057171) on the Apple dev forums where they talked about using a class method that returns type Self, but I am unable to figure out how to go about this.

```
typealias JSONObject = AnyObject
protocol JSONParseable {
    static func fromJSONObject(jsonObject: JSONObject) throws -> Self
}

extension NSURL: JSONParseable {
    class func fromJSONObject(jsonObject: JSONObject) throws -> Self {
        guard let jsonString = jsonObject as? String else {
            throw JSONParseError.ConversionError(message: "blah")
        }
        guard let result = NSURL(string: jsonString) else {
            throw JSONParseError.ConversionError(message: "blah")
        }
        return result // Error: cannot convert return expression of type 'NSURL' to return type 'Self'
    }
}
```

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244732/swift-protocol-defining-class-method-returning-self) but the answer there was to mark the class as final -- I obviously can't do that on a Foundation class.

Could someone explain how to fix my approach above? Or suggest a different approach for adding protocol conformance to Foundation classes?

Comment: Yes, thank you! I went with the self.init(...) approach.

Comment: don't forget to upvote if you liked the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `self.init(....)` instead of `NSURL(....)` since this also needs to work for `NSURL` subclasses.

```
protocol JSONParseable {
    static func fromJSONObject(jsonObject: JSONObject) throws -> Self
}

extension NSURL : JSONParseable {

    class func fromJSONObject(jsonObject: JSONObject) throws -> Self {

        guard let jsonString = jsonObject as? String else {
            throw JSONParseError.ConversionError(message: "blah")
        }
        guard let result = self.init(string: jsonString) else {
            throw JSONParseError.ConversionError(message: "blah")
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

---

Hack : define a `typealias T`, this will return an `NSURL` even for subclasses.

```
protocol JSONParseable {
    typealias T = Self
    static func fromJSONObject(jsonObject: JSONObject) throws -> T
}

extension NSURL : JSONParseable {

    typealias T = NSURL
    class func fromJSONObject(jsonObject: JSONObject) throws -> T {

        guard let jsonString = jsonObject as? String else {
            throw JSONParseError.ConversionError(message: "blah")
        }
        guard let result = NSURL(string: jsonString) else {
            throw JSONParseError.ConversionError(message: "blah")
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

---